# Тире при присоединительной/пояснительной конструкции

Tags: пунктуация, тире

*Не знаю, что тебе придётся сделать — проехать 100 метров по тротуару, пролить кофе на охранника, — но к деловой встрече с VIP-заказчиками ты должен успеть.*

*Не знаю, что тебе придётся сделать: проехать 100 метров по тротуару, пролить кофе на охранника — но к деловой встрече с VIP-заказчиками ты должен успеть.*

Какой это тип конструкции и как её лучше оформить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) — Не знаю, что тебе придётся сделать, — проехать 100 метров по тротуару, пролить кофе на охранника, — но к деловой встрече с VIP-заказчиками ты должен успеть.

**Вставная конструкция:** два тире, первая запятая закрывает придаточное, вторая запятая относится к структуре сложного предложения.

(2) — Не знаю, что тебе придётся сделать: проехать 100 метров по тротуару, пролить кофе на охранника, но к деловой встрече с VIP-заказчиками ты должен успеть.

**Придаточное  с обобщающим словом *сделать*,**  тире перед  НО не ставится, только запятая, отнесенная к структуре сложного предложения.

Интонация разная: в предложение 1  **присоединительный** характер ряда, вставочная интонация. В предложении 2  ряд входит в основное предложение, его статус **более значимый.**

Comment: А вам не кажется, что вставка относится к слову "что", находящемся внутри придаточного, соответственно вставка относится к придаточному и запятая не нужна?

Comment: Грамматически вставка не связана с предложением,  а по смыслу она связана с СПП.  У Розенталя: 2) перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура первой части основного предложения: Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123  Это общие правила оформления вставных конструкций, если вы собираетесь использовать такую конструкцию

Comment: Можно поставить после второй запятой тире в случае, когда у нас обобщающее слово? Розенталь вроде пишет: тире ставится или опускается.

Comment: Да,  у Розенталя  есть такая информация, но перед союзом НО у него нет тире. Возможно, здесь нужно ориентироваться на наличие паузы.  С другой стороны, можно поставить запятую и тире как единый знак, чтобы обозначить увеличенную паузу при сочинительной связи перед союзом НО в сложном предложении.  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133  § 114.  Примечание. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения может стоять запятая и тире как единый знак препинания: Оскалив зубы, староста стал драть его кнутом по чем попало, — и от боли и от ужаса Аверкий проснулся весь в слезах (Бун.);